# Mostrar imagen desde AWS

Tags: laravel, imagen, aws, tcpdf

Buen día, estoy trayendo una imagen desde AWS que posteriormente muestro en un pdf, pero a la hora de llegar esta me saca lo siguiente:

**HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foto_prenda_1669258511.jpg
Content-Length: 617476 Content-Type: image/jpeg Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2022 12:25:59 GM**

No se alcanza a visualizar la imagen en el documento pdf.

De esta forma traigo la imagen de AWS

```
 public function pdf($id)
{

    $foto = Storage::disk('s3')->response('sio/servicio-cliente/sc-reporte-prendas/2022/foto_prenda_1669258511.jpg');

    return $foto;
}
```

Estoy usando Laravel 9 y TCPDF para el pdf.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el problema que está experimentando puede estar relacionado con la forma en que se devuelve la imagen desde su función. Cuando usa el método response() para obtener una imagen de AWS S3, devuelve la imagen como un objeto Response, que contiene los encabezados HTTP y el cuerpo de la imagen.

Para mostrar la imagen en su PDF, necesitará extraer los datos binarios de la imagen del objeto Response y pasarla directamente a la biblioteca PDF. La mayoría de las bibliotecas PDF, incluido TCPDF, tienen métodos para agregar imágenes a un PDF que toman los datos binarios de la imagen como entrada.

A continuación, se muestra un ejemplo de cómo modificar su función para extraer los datos binarios de la imagen y pasarla a TCPDF:

```
public function pdf($id)
{
    // Obtener la imagen de AWS S3 como un objeto Response
    $response = Storage::disk('s3')->response('sio/servicio-cliente/sc-reporte-prendas/2022/foto_prenda_1669258511.jpg');

    // Extraer los datos binarios de la imagen del objeto Response
    $image_data = (string) $response->getBody();

    // Crear un nuevo documento PDF
    $pdf = new TCPDF();

    // Agregar la imagen al PDF utilizando los datos binarios
    $pdf->Image($image_data, 10, 10);

    // Guardar el PDF y devolverlo al usuario
    return $pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
}
```

En este ejemplo, usamos el método getBody() del objeto Response para extraer los datos binarios de la imagen y luego pasamos estos datos directamente al método Image() de TCPDF para agregar la imagen al PDF. Esto debería permitirle mostrar la imagen en su PDF sin problemas.